# How to present non-uniform data

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on a relatively simple android application: there's an sqlite database, and the user is presented with a list of the titles, and upon clicking on an item, the entire details of that record are displayed. But the problem is that the data is not uniform; some rows have only a couple of lines of text, some rows have a line of text and then an audio file, some rows have two or more audio files plus some text. How should I present this data, and more importantly, how do I store this data?

P.S. I want the audio to play at their respective places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ii've solved the issue. the data is stored using two tables. example:

```
table 1:
id       title
---      -----
1        blah
2        blahblah2
3        blah3

table 2 [details]:
id      text     img     aud
---     ----     ---     ---
1       jsgsg    img11   aud11
1       segs     img12   aud12
1       jbcj     img13   aud13
2       nvnh     img21   aud21
2       kjbj     img22   aud22
3       jhbb     img31   aud31
```

and the data is presented in inflatable listview containing one textview, one imageview and one audio button, the visibility of each depending on the value in the database(view invisible if value is null). one list each for all items with the same id.